# How to set timer for a row in google sheets

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-chrome-extension

I would like to set a timer for an entire row in google sheets where a user can start entering data in the second row only after a certain time after starting row one.

Example: If a user starts filling cells in row 1 then they should be able to fill the data in the second only after the timer ends.

Could anyone suggest me how to get started or suggest me a chrome extension for this use?

You could also suggest me on how to build the chrome extension I can try it along with my colleagues.

Comment: You can start with the Protection class of app script [Class Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection)

Answer (score 0):

This function uses an onEdit trigger to impose a 20 second delay between editing rows.  It may not be exactly what you want but perhaps it's a start.  It uses PropertiesService to keep state.  I think user properties would be a better choice but script properties are easier to develop with since you can modify them directly in the script editor.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  const delay=20000;
  let ms=Number(new Date().valueOf()).toFixed();
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet10') {
    const ps=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    let dObj=ps.getProperties();
    if(dObj.hasOwnProperty('row') && dObj.hasOwnProperty('delay')) {
      if(dObj.row!=e.range.rowStart && Number(ms-dObj.delay)<delay) {
        e.range.setValue(e.oldValue);
        e.source.toast('Sorry you have ' + (delay-Number(ms-dObj.delay))/1000 + ' seconds left.');
      }else{
        ps.setProperties({'row':e.range.rowStart,'delay':ms});
      }    
    }else{
      ps.setProperties({'row':e.range.rowStart,'delay':ms});
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue with Protections:

[Class Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) is commonly used to protect ranges from being edited. It is not appropriate for your situation, though, because, as specified [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#removeeditorsemailaddresses), users who are executing the script cannot remove themselves from the list of editors:

> Neither the owner of the spreadsheet nor the current user can be removed.

#### Using oldValue:

Because of this, the best way to go would be to use the parameter `oldValue` from the [onEdit event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit).

An `onEdit` trigger runs every time a user edits a cell. In it, you can use:

- [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) to store useful information: (1) whether it is the first time row 1 is edited (`isNotFirstTime`), and (2) when was last time first row was edited (`startTime`).
- [Event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) to get information on the edited cell (its row, its old value, etc.).

You can do something along the following lines (check comments):

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var current = new Date(); // Current date
  var range = e.range;
  var editedRow = range.getRow();
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var waitingTime = 20 * 1000; // 20 seconds
  var isNotFirstTime = props.getProperty("isNotFirstTime"); // Check if first row was previously edited
  var startTime = new Date(props.getProperty("startTime")); // Time when first row was first edited
  if (editedRow === 1 && !isNotFirstTime) { // Check that (1) edited row is first one, (2) it was not edited before
    props.setProperty("startTime", current.toString()); // If it's first time first row was edited, store current time
    Utilities.sleep(waitingTime); // Wait for 20 seconds
    props.setProperty("isNotFirstTime", true); // Store: first row was previously edited
  }
  // Check that (1) second row edited, (2) Less than 20 seconds passed since first time first row was edited:
  if (editedRow === 2 && (current - startTime) < waitingTime) {
    range.setValue(e.oldValue || ""); // Set previous value to edited cell (this avoids editing cells)
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)
- [onEdit Event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)
- [Class PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)